# Ember Data: How to make a POST request?

Tags: post, ember.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, ember-data

**Summary**: I haven't found any option of sending POST requests via Ember Data, and would really appreciate your sophisticated help. The [documentation](http://emberjs.joefiorini.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/) says one should use the Create function, but there are no examples for it anywhere. You don't have to read the entire details here, this is my major question.

**Background**: I want that as soon as the user logs in with a Facebook login, his signedRequest would be sent to the RESTful server and it will send back a JSON that would provide more information about him from my database.

**My architecture**: By my research I've discovered that signedRequest is the prefered way (compare to accessToken) to make this secure and quick, because it does not rely on any further Facebook Server check and therefore decreases the 'IO'. It only depands on AppId And AppSecret for decoding. Security and agility are important to me due to the RESTful architecture in which authentication should be done per each communication (am I wrong?).

**What I'v succeeded**: I've managed to make the facebook login and the decoding logic of the signedRequest.
(If this is the first login, the logic on the server will insert him to the database).

**The problem**: At first I made a GET request to the Web API I've prepared with the signedRequest, it worked well untill I had concated a long-string and then
got "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request".

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
FBSignedRequest: "non",
  actions: {
    login: function(){
        this.set("FBSignedRequest", FBApp.FBUser.signedRequest);
        this.store.find('user', this.get("FBSignedRequest")); //want to make it POST
    }
  }
});
```

The GET request was something like:

```
http://localhost:54441/api/users/iAMveRyLongStrINgWHichRepreSEnTsASignEDReQueSt
```

Then I thought to myself that this is because of the complexity of the signedRequest,
so the second way is to make it POST request. But, surprisingly, there is nothing about making POST requests on the internet. Am I missing something here? I have found only payloads and serialization, but am not sure those are necessary.

Could you help me please?

Comment: I haven't found any way to bind the server with Ember Data Post request, and no one here answered. So I feel like Ember Data is still not a smart choice, and therefore I'll choose to do that by a manual Ember.$.ajax while enabling CORS on the server.

Comment: Do you have the answer ? Because I need to do it too..

Comment: Hi @SuperMarco, truth be said, I have gave up this whole consept of Ember Data. It was sound nice at the beginning to have this built-in ORM to "do the work" for you. But for my opinion it is also very limited. So now I'm doing a manual Ember.$.ajax and am getting what ever I want without any restrictions! It is kind of disappointing to lose it, beacause what does Ember worth now? But at least we are getting the handlebar auto updating feature from that framework. If you have discovered something intersting, please let me know.

Comment: Well I still looking into it, but most likely I will do the same as you such as a manual Ember ajax. If I find anything in the meantime I'ill post it here ;)

Comment: @SuperMarco, hope you'll find :) Something to help you to combine manual Ember ajax and Ember Data is using Push. You can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646993/ember-authentication-paradigm and http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/