# Ember Authentication paradigm

Tags: ajax, ember.js, ember-data

Let's consider a trivial use case: User edits his profile + we have a RESTful server. This means we have to 
send a token to the server and at the same time the new information about the editing. First, the server has to decode the token, and later to CRUD the DB. We want also to send back to the client a new json model about the new user profile.

BUT the token is really a huge one, so we must send it with a POST request. We can send the additional information as a query string at the same HTTP Post. Ember Data doesn't give us the ability to decide on sending a POST request. So we have to write a manual Ember.$.ajax. But how would we retrieve the new user model to Ember? We want to take advantage of Ember Data ORM's relationships and not reinventing the wheel.

Just for the record, the manual valid post request on the EditController is (after enabling CORS on the server)+(fBSignedRequest=> the token in my case):

```
Ember.$.ajax('http://myapi.com/api/usrEdit?Name='+myNewName, {  
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: "json",
             data: {fBSignedRequest: this.get("FBSignedRequest")},
             success: function(data, response) {
                 console.log(data, response);
                 App.newUserProfile = data; //want it to become a part of the ED ORM
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 console.log('error')
             }
});
```

This is really a trivial task to ask. Why couldn't I found any answer for over a month for this? How would you do the combination of a manual ajax and a build in Ember Data ORM?

If you have another idea about this whole authentication, I will be glad to hear.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply `push` the model you retrieve via your request into the store. See http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the solution! I'll read more about the push and pushMany